# iPhone - does scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval retain userInfo param ?

Tags: iphone, cocoa, memory-management, nstimer, retain

In that piece of code, I have both NSLog that says dict has a retain count of 1.
As the timer can be triggered in a long time if there are many objects into the array, May I retain dict given into user info ? Because I guess it's autorelease, and the scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval does not seems to retain it.

Theoricaly ?
Practically ?

```
- (void) doItWithDelay
{
    NSArray* jobToDo = /* get an autorelease array */

    NSTimeInterval nextLaunch = 0.1;
    int i=1;

    for (NSDictionary* dict in jobToDo) {
        NSLog(@"dict %d has %d retain count", i++, [dict retainCount]);

        // HERE [dict retain] ???
        [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:nextLaunch target:self selector:@selector(doIt:) userInfo:dict repeats:NO];   
        nextLaunch += 1.0;
    }
}

- (void) doIt:(NSTimer*)theTimer 
{    
    NSDictionary* dict = [theTimer userInfo];

    NSLog(@"dict has now %d retain count", [dict retainCount]);

    // Do some stuff with dict
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apple NSTimer document say that it will retain the userInfo. Below is quoted from the document...

> The object you specify is retained by the timer and released when the timer is invalidated.

Your second NSLog say 1, so i guess it already been autoreleased but the timer still retain it.

EDIT: As bbum suggested, we should not rely on retain count. So we're lucky that the doc state it clearly.

Comment: The absolute retain count of an object is meaningless.  Your conclusion is incorrect;  `autorelease` does not impact the retain directly.

Answer (score 3):

As Khomsan said, the docs explicitly state that the object is retained.

End of story.

`retainCount` is useless;  don't call it.  The absolute retain count of an object is an implementation detail.

Answer (score 0):

do not invalidate NSTimer before attempting to its userInfo.